# Get text and use for aria-label on each

Tags: jquery, function, label, each

I want to get the text from each a.parent_link and apply it as an aria-label on each corresponding toggle button (button.sub-expand_collapse). The final result I want is if aria-expanded = true add aria-label= close + (text) and if aria-expanded = false add aria-label= expand + (text).

The first part gives me the text

```
$(".togSubList").each(function () {
        var bob = $(this).find(".parent_link").text();
        console.log(bob);
    });
```

But I can't get each one to add a the aria-label.

```
     $(".togSubList").each(function () {
        var bob = $(this).find(".parent_link").text();
        //console.log(bob);
        $(".sub-expand_collapse").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("aria-label","expand " + bob)
        }); 
    });
```

HTML

```
   <li class="sub_p01 togSubList">

        <button class="sub-expand_collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <a id="subLnk_01" class="parent_link menu_p01" href="m01_c01_p01.html"><strong>Space saving widgets</strong></a> 
        <ul aria-labelledby="subLnk_01" class="sub_items">
            list of links
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Your code works on my test: https://jsfiddle.net/8xgtcg87/

Maybe there's a jQuery load error somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  Don't need second each function because inside `LI` you have only one element so just use `node traverse` . and `find` the element like this . and apply the `attribute` .

```js
$(".togSubList").each(function () {
        var bob = $(this).find(".parent_link").text();

        $(this).find(".sub-expand_collapse[aria-expanded='false']").attr("aria-label","expand " + bob);
         $(this).find(".sub-expand_collapse[aria-expanded='true']").attr("aria-label","close " + bob);
            

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sub_p01 togSubList">

        <button class="sub-expand_collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <a id="subLnk_01" class="parent_link menu_p01" href="m01_c01_p01.html"><strong>Space saving widgets</strong></a> 
        <ul aria-labelledby="subLnk_01" class="sub_items">
            list of links
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I just have to wrap it in an in click so it triggers each time the button is toggled. :-)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already looping through each ".togSubList" you dont need to loop through each toggle button within that. Just use "this" as a reference and target both accordingly.

The only problem is that you will need to re-run the function whenever the button is expanded/collapsed.

```
$(".togSubList").each(function () {
    var bob = $(this).find(".parent_link").text();
    //console.log(bob);
    $(".sub-expand_collapse[aria-expanded='false']", this).attr("aria-label","expand " + bob);
    $(".sub-expand_collapse[aria-expanded='true']", this).attr("aria-label”,”close " + bob);        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @partypete25.